# preg_replace for bbcodes: How can I improve security?

Tags: php, image, security, tinymce, preg-replace

In order to work with bbcodes within tinymce (standalone) I created this code:

```
private function regExUrl($content) {
    if(isset($content) && is_string($content)) {
        return  preg_replace(
        array('|(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)|', '|\[img\](.*)\[\/img\]|', '|\[b\]|', '|\[/b\]|', '|\[i\]|', '|\[/i\]|', '|\[url=../../../../\]|', '|\[/url\]|'), 
        array('<a href="$1">$1</a>', '<img src="$1" class="wide" />', '<b>', '</b>', '<i>', '</i>', '<url>', '</url>'),  
        $content);

    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

How can I improve security of that code before I integrate it into my live-website? Or is it ok?
The textbox for inserting pics and news  is within a pass-protected area.

thanks for your help

Comment: Are you also sanitizing the data or just parsing it?

Comment: I don't use sanitize-filters. They are new to me (I am newbie), but I use strip_tags, in order to avoid html-code. Is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

Exploits at first glance (there are probably more):

```
http://www.example.com/xxx?xxx"onmouseover="alert('XSS');
[img]javascript:alert('XSS')[/img]
[img]xxx" onerror="alert('XSS')[/img]
```

Additionally `strip_tags()` is not intended as a security function; there have been ways around it in previous PHP versions and if run with allowed-tags it is entirely insecure. Also naturally it would disallow legitimate use of the less-than symbol in comments.

(On a non-security note, it's also possible to have mismatched tags, messing up the rest of the page, and I can't work out what `[url]` is supposed to be doing at all.)

Writing a markup generator securely is hard. Normally that means the advice is to use a known-good library, but personally I've never seen a watertight PHP bbcode implementation (suggestions welcome). If you want to allow HTML-style markup then look at HTML Purifier. There are other simpler user-facing mini-markup languages, such as Markdown, but again finding libraries that support them properly and securely can be a challenge.